# Tricks for naming worlds

Tags: worldbuilding-process, names

One thing I have seen time and time again are people giving their worlds names.

Personally, I find this a rather difficult process, since everyone in my world calls their Earth 'Earth' and the people do not name their world any other way.

So I have come here to ask **how to make a fitting world name**, or what common, reliable methods there are to create a unique name.

Does one use name generators, portmanteaus, proto-constructed-languages, simply garbled jumbles or something entirely different?

Comment: Not everyone calls Earth "Earth". I'm a Romanian. We don't call our world "Earth" -- it's not even a possible Romanian word; the closest would be Ărs or Ărf. We call it "Pământ". French people call it "Terre", a word which means "earth", "ground", "land" or "country"; their name for England is "Angleterre", Land of the English. Russians call it "Zyemlya", a word which, means both "earth" and "land"; for example, it is the word they use for the German federal states. The conclusions are that (1) the native name could well mean "Land" or "Country" and (2) you should leave it untranslated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Consider what the cultures of your setting would think about their world.**

Many cultures on Earth give our planet a name that is some variant on 'Land', 'Soil', or 'Dirt'. This is not ubiquitous however.

If the Romans had figured out that the Earth was another planet akin to those they knew, they might have called her Vesta, after their goddess of Hearth and Home.

In terms of what word your characters would actually use in your text, you need to make a decision about whether you are translating their word into the language you are writing in (in my case English), or whether you are preserving their own word in making it clear through context what they are talking about.

In the later case, you might even find that you want to do a bit of conlanging.

Comment: Why Vesta, when they already had a handy "Terra Mater" for that role?

Comment: @StarfishPrime They might indeed have continued to use Terra Mater, but they were unaware that the Earth was a planet at that time. Upon discovering it was a planet in orbit of Sol, and given the names of the other planets, it follows that they might have changed how they considered the world. It would have been entirely Roman for Terra Mater and Vesta to have been syncretised into one goddess.

Answer (score 1):

**Take a word you associate with your world and swap out a few letters** here and there.

A classic example: Eragon (from Dragon)

It is quick, easy and leads to interesting results.

A few shortcomings of this strategy are:

- It can be hard to find a word you associate with the world
- It can be hard to make the name unique, especially with very short or long words (too short and you get another word, too long and the original word is quickly identified)
- It can be hard to pronounce or remember the resulting name